# Raspberry PI 4 Chrome Menu Board Issues

Tags: chromium, settings, screen-saver

Hello everyone pretty new to using raspberrypi. So a resturant I use to work at bought a service where someone makes they a digital menu thats hosted on the web. The reason for it being on the web as opposed to just an image is because they can make changes to it through a dashboard and it updates on the fly.

The issue im having is whenever I try to have two chrome instances open and put both of them on fullscreen everything bugs out and I get these white lines. I uploaded an image for you guys to see. If I have one full screen chrome open everything is fine but once I open another chrome full screen everything just starts messing up.

Heres the pic:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cb8v.jpg

Comment: Welcome @jthedev How are you getting both chromes to be fullscreen? Your pic looks like non-fullscreen chrome and that line your mouse is on is the edge of the chrome window. Please update your question and we'll assist :) EDIT: What version of RPi do you have? Does it have 2 small hdmi connectors or only 1 large.